# PHP Sending email using Swiftmailer and Gmail appending the orginal email

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I just want to know, how to hide the original email when sending email using Swiftmailer i am using below code on my localhost, and manage to send emails but there's one thing that i notice that its still showing my gmail account on the side of the alias and not showing testemail@email.com.

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, "ssl")
  ->setUsername('mygmailaccount@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword('myPassword');


$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Test Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('testemail@email.com' => 'CompanyName'))
  ->setTo(array('toemail@email.com'))
  ->setBody('This is a test mail.');

$result = $mailer->send($message);
?>
```

When received on my email using outlook, is this a security on outlook? or my code needs some tweaking, thanks in advance!

```
From    : CompanyName [mygmailaccount@gmail.com]
To      : toemail@email.com
CC      :
Subject :
```

Comment: I don't think Gmail allows you to send e-mails from other addresses when using their SMTP. They will always use your email address as "from" regardless of what you set., unless you have added and confirmed that address on that account: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en

Comment: @Magnis Eroksson so for security reason gmail still shows my gmail account on the side, ok i understand.

Comment: Updated the comment. You might be able to if you register and confirm  the address as a "send from"-address. Check the link I posted. It might help you.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson i tried it but it requires to add a different SMTP server so looks like i need to find another way, but appreciate the response, cheers!